# Why am I seeing duplicate packets when using sockets to receive UDP broadcasts on Windows7 but not XP?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, windows-7, windows-xp

*Let me state up front, that sockets programming is fairly new to me.  Also, the code I'm asking about has worked for several years and the problem I discuss only began when we changed from supporting Windows XP to Windows 7.*

I am working on a C# application that sends and receives network packets.  It's sort of a network sniffer type application, so data integrity is very important.  Ever since we migrated from **Windows XP** to **Windows 7**, when we UDP Broadcast (255.255.255.255) packets, we receive the packets twice.  (i.e. I send 610 packets, I receive 1220 packets).

**I have verified with WireShark that the packets are only being received once.**  Also, we have some older C++ sockets code that had been replaced by .NET code.  The older C++ code does not indicate duplicates.  These both indicate 610 packets sent, 610 packets received.

The code is highly threaded and split among various classes, but putting some of the pieces together, the receive code looks like the following:

```
public class RawSocket : Socket
{
    public RawSocket( IPAddress address, int receiveBufferSize, bool receiveAll )
        : base( AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP )
    {
        Bind( new IPEndPoint( address, 0 ) );

        ReceiveBufferSize = receiveBufferSize;

        ReceiveTimeout = 500; // half-a-second

        if ( receiveAll ) {
            byte[] incoming = BitConverter.GetBytes( 1 );
            byte[] outgoing = BitConverter.GetBytes( 1 );
            IOControl( IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, incoming, outgoing );
        }
    }
}

_device = new RawSocket( /* IP Address Specified Here */ );
```

And then in the code responsible for reading...

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[ 65536 ];
int read = _device.Receive( buffer );
if (read > 0)
{
    _packet = new byte[ size ];
    _packet.BlockCopy( buffer, offset, size );
}
```

So my question is, what changed with the .NET sockets API between Windows XP and Windows 7 that would cause this behavior?  I have read threads that indicate there are differences, but nothing like this.  Tracing through the code makes me think that it has to do with the behavior of the `Receive()` method on the `Socket` class that may be different.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the spec this is expected behaviour.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.iocontrolcode(v=vs.110).aspx says that ReceiveAll equals to the Winsock 2 SIO_RCVALL constant.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee309610(v=vs.85).aspx says:

> On Windows Server 2008 and earlier, the SIO_RCVALL IOCTL setting would
>   not capture local packets sent out of a network interface. This
>   included packets received on another interface and forwarded out the
>   network interface specified for the SIO_RCVALL IOCTL.
>
> On Windows 7
>   and Windows Server 2008 R2 , this was changed so that local packets
>   sent out of a network interface are also captured. This includes
>   packets received on another interface and then forwarded out the
>   network interface bound to the socket with SIO_RCVALL IOCTL.

Comment: Thanks.  I had come across that article as well.  It certainly explains why I see the behavior when I'm transmitting and receiving on the same computer.  However, I still observe this behavior on the receiving computer when transmitting from another computer.  Could is possibly have something to do with how XP and Win7 deal with broadcasts to 255.255.255.255?  Also, my raw socket is collecting in a windows service and then using 127.0.0.1 for IPC to transmit the data to the front end application.  Perhaps it's catching that as well?

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your question carefully enough, I think I should delete it. So some new thoughts: What address are you binding the socket to? Is there some kind of IP bridging or routing active? When talking about IPC to 127.0.0.1 you do not just forward the IP packets to front end or do you?

Comment: I wouldn't delete the answer.  You've provided some very useful information.  I'll have to get with one of the other engineers to get definitive answers to those questions.  I think I know the answers, but I've not been on this project long enough to say for sure.